# Standalone ubuntu desktop integration to AD DNS

Tags: platform-integration

Is it possible to integrate AD DNS while installing standalone Ubuntu desktop or it needs os customization support.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.